# Can I use awk to perform some number or string operations, without specifying a file as input?

Tags: awk, gawk

Awk has builtin functions which are operating on numbers and strings. That is exactly what a programming language does.

That makes me wonder if I can use awk to perform some number or string operations using awk, without specifying a file as input? Can awk work without input from file or stdin?

For example, I would like awk to evaluate `1+2`, and hardcode the "input" 1 and 2 in a awk program. Okay, I answer myself:

```
$ awk "BEGIN{print 1+2}"
3
```

But I am surprised that awk doesn't wait for input from stdin since I don't specify an input file. Why not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design. It's documented in (at least) the GNU man page for `awk`

> If the program consists entirely of `BEGIN` blocks, then execution terminates, else an input stream is opened and execution continues.

From [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/awk.html):

> If an `awk` program consists of only actions with the pattern `BEGIN`, and the `BEGIN` action contains no `getline` function, `awk` shall exit without reading its input when the last statement in the last `BEGIN` action is executed.

Comment: Thanks. Is this the only case when awk doesn't expect an input? Or I should ask how you would write an awk program if you don't want awk to expect an input?

Comment: @Tim This is the only case.